# Prefixes "вос-", "воз-", "вс-" and "вз-"

Tags: глаголы, приставки

There are pairs of verbs with similar meaning and similar prefixes such as

> Восход солнца - Солнце взошло. - Побеги всходят.
>   Он воззвал к милосердию. - Эти люди взывают к разуму, а не к чувствам.
>   Он воздел руки к солнцу - Прежде чем вздевать руки к небу, не лучше ли сосредоточиться на насущных проблемах?

Are prefixes *вз-* and *вс-*, *воз-* and *вос-* phonetic variants of each other? Or do they differ in meaning as well?
According to what rules are *вос-*, *воз-*, *вс-* and *вз-* alternated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All those prefixes are derived from **въз*.

During the fall of the reduced *ъ* transformed into *о* in strong positions and fell in weak positions.

It fell in proper Russian words: *всход < *възходъ* etc. but retained in writing in OCS.

Russian rendition of CS words required voicing of *ъ* in this prefix so CS loanwords use *вос*: *восход < (CS.) восходъ < (OCS.) възходъ*

Answer (score 3):

[Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации (1956) § 50.](http://gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=sogl&text=19_14)
В приставках без-, воз-, вз-, из-, низ-, раз-, роз-, чрез- (через-) перед глухими к, п, с, т, ф, х, ц, ч, ш, щ пишется с вместо з, например: бесполезный, воспитать, вспахать, искусать, ниспровергнуть, рассыпать, роспись, чересполосица, но: безвкусный, бездарный, вздремнуть, возбудить, избавить и т. п

Звонкая "з" в приставках приглушается, если за ней стоит глухая согласная. Это правило действует и в произношении, и в написании. вос- и воз- это не две разные приставки, это одна и та же приставка воз-, употребление воз- или вос- подчиняется только правилу из § 50, смысл/значение слова при этом не меняется.

Comment: That, indeed, is only a half of the answer.

Comment: @Olga I added some explanation. My answer still incomplete?

Comment: I was also asking whether вс- and вос- were two different prefixes or positional variants of the same prefix. Quassnoi answered this part of the question (but not the part about вс-\вз-). I decided to upvote your answer, and to accept his. The difference is in 5 reputation points.